# What is the difference between bulk delete and destroy in sequelize?

Tags: sequelize.js, destroy, bulk-delete

I am trying to delete all my records from a table using sequelize but saw that there are two possible functions to use: `queryInterface.bulkDelete` and `queryInterface.destroy` . Can someone tell me what are the differences between these two and which one should I use? The documentation does not do a great job apparently.

Comment: Is it queryInterface.destroy? Are you sure about that? Because as I know, destroy is a method for model instaces. Which removes the instace from DB. queryInterface.bulkDelete is sending a new query to remove more than one data from DB

Comment: What version of sequelize are you using? There is no `destroy` method on `QueryInterface`